# PHP - remove comma from the last loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a PHP while LOOP, and I want to remove last comma `,` from `echo '],';` if it is last loop

```
            while($ltr = mysql_fetch_array($lt)){
                echo '[';
                echo $ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'];
                echo '],';
            }
```

Comment: do not use mysql_*. try PDO::

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = '';
while($ltr = mysql_fetch_array($lt)){
    $str .= '[';
    $str .= $ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'];
    $str .= '],';
}

echo rtrim($str, ",");
```

this will remove the last `,` from string

Answer (score 7):

Create an array with the elements as you go along so that they look like `array = ([ELEMENT INFO], [ELEMENT INFO], [ELEMENT INFO])` and then `implode` the array with a comma.

Comment: This method produces the nicest code and I don't have any reason to think it will be less efficient than any other, less elegant methods, with the possible exception of if there are a huge number of elements.

Answer (score 4):

I think the systemic solution is following:

```
$separator = '';
while($ltr = mysql_fetch_array($lt)){
    echo $separator;
    echo '[';
    echo $ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'];
    echo ']';
    if (!$separator) $separator = ', ';
}
```

No call for `count()`, no additional iteration of `implode()`, no additional string operations, ready for any (unpredictable) number of results.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($lt);
for ($i=0;$i<=(count($result)-1);$i++) {
    $ltr = $result[$i];
    echo '[';
    echo $ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'];
    echo ']';
    if(!count($result)-1 == $i){
        echo ',';
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer instead of using rtrim as you don't have to maintain a string the size of which depends on loop.

Answer (score 1):

Check how many entries you have, make a "Counter" and a condition to only put the comma when its not the last loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array();
while($ltr = mysql_fetch_array($lt)){
    $arr[] = '[' . $ltr['days'] . ' ,' . $ltr['name'] . ']';
}

echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$res_array = array();

while($ltr = mysql_fetch_array($lt)){
   $res_array[] = '['.$ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'].']';
}

$str = implode(",",$res_array);
echo $str;
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli OR PDO

Answer (score 1):

Save the response as a var instead of echoing it and then remove the final character at the end using substr.

```
      $response = "";
       while($ltr = mysql_fetch_array($lt)){
            $response .= '[';
            $response .= $ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'];
            $response .= '],';
        }
      echo substr($response, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this one works
$result = mysql_fetch_array($lt);
for ($i=0;$i<=(count($result)-1);$i++) {
    $ltr = $result[$i];
    echo '[';
    echo $ltr['days']. ' ,'. $ltr['name'];
    echo ']';
    if(count($result)-1 != $i){
        echo ',';
    }
}
```