# Remove separator of last menu

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to remove last separator after Login Menu.
Here is my code and output.

```
              <?php
                if (!empty($topmenu) && !empty($menulist)) {
                    foreach ($topmenu as $mainparent) {
                        $arry = getmenuvalue($mainparent->id, $menulist, MAINURL);
                        if (isset($mainparent->children) && !empty($mainparent->children)) {
                            echo '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="' . $arry['url'] . '" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' . $arry['name'] . '<span class="caret"> </span></a>';

                            echo '</li>';
                            echo '<li> | </li>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<li><a href="' . $arry['url'] . '">' . $arry['name'] . '</a></li>';
                            echo '<li> | </li>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Result of this code is

```
Home | Register | Login |
```

I want to Remove last Separator after Login menu.
I want result like this.

```
Home | Register | Login
```

Comment: use the array length to get last element and wirte code(` echo '<li> | </li>';`) with in condition

Comment: if it is not last element of array then print echo '<li> | </li>'; else '' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701286/php-remove-comma-from-the-last-loop

Comment: give me code i am student

Comment: use my code for example @devpro

Comment: i am not php developer. but your code like jsp so i implemented code by see other post in stackoverflow. i will give you a suggestion. now you are student and you are in initial level, logic are same in all technologies, use your effort first and write your own logic, you feel your mind is grow up and your technical skill also. If you are not solve this then asked to other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
                if (!empty($topmenu) && !empty($menulist)) {
                   $count = count($topmenu);
                   $i = 1;
                    foreach ($topmenu as $mainparent) {

                        $arry = getmenuvalue($mainparent->id, $menulist, MAINURL);
                        if (isset($mainparent->children) && !empty($mainparent->children)) {

                            echo '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="' . $arry['url'] . '" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' . $arry['name'] . '<span class="caret"> </span></a>';

                            echo '</li>';
                            if($count != $i)  
                            echo '<li> | </li>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<li><a href="' . $arry['url'] . '">' . $arry['name'] . '</a></li>';
                            if($count != $i)
                            echo '<li> | </li>';
                        }
                     $i++;
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example:

```
<?
$array = array('One','Two','Three'); // your array

$count = count($array); // check the array count
$i = 1; // use incremental
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $separator = ($i == $count ? '' : '|'); // compare if last index use empty else separator 
    echo $value. $separator; // print separator with value
    $i++; // +1 in every iteration. 
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
One|Two|Three
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Example with your code

```
<?
if (!empty($topmenu) && !empty($menulist)) {

    $count = count($topmenu);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($topmenu as $mainparent) {
        $arry = getmenuvalue($mainparent->id, $menulist, MAINURL);
        if (isset($mainparent->children) && !empty($mainparent->children)) {
            echo '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="' . $arry['url'] . '" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' . $arry['name'] . '<span class="caret"> </span></a>';

            echo '</li>';            
        } else {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $arry['url'] . '">' . $arry['name'] . '</a></li>';
            //echo '<li> | </li>';
        }
        if($i == $count ? '' : '<li> | </li>');
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

**Side Note:**

I am not sure about the `$topmenu` check `count($topmenu);` if you get the count it will work. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect your list items and concat them using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($topmenu) && !empty($menulist)) {

        $listItems = array();
        foreach ($topmenu as $mainparent) {
            $arry = getmenuvalue($mainparent->id, $menulist, MAINURL);
            if (isset($mainparent->children) && !empty($mainparent->children)) {
                $listItems[] = '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="' . $arry['url'] . '" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' . $arry['name'] . '<span class="caret"> </span></a></li>';
            } else {
                $listItems[] = '<li><a href="' . $arry['url'] . '">' . $arry['name'] . '</a></li>';
            }
        }

        echo implode('<li> | </li>', $listItems);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<?php
    if (!empty($topmenu) && !empty($menulist)) {
        foreach ($topmenu as $key => $mainparent) {
            $arry = getmenuvalue($mainparent->id, $menulist, MAINURL);
            if (isset($mainparent->children) && !empty($mainparent->children)) {
                echo '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="' . $arry['url'] . '" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' . $arry['name'] . '<span class="caret"> </span></a>';

                echo '</li>';
                //echo '<li> | </li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="' . $arry['url'] . '">' . $arry['name'] . '</a></li>';
                //echo '<li> | </li>';
            }

            end($topmenu);
            if ($key !== key($topmenu)) {
                echo '<li> | </li>';
            } 

        }
    }
?>
```